# Trajectory Planning and Optimal Control

Tags: control-systems, numerical-algorithms

When finding control inputs for ODE systems, gradient based solutions are often used. With the increase computational power will these solutions still be important over things like Monte-Carlo searching and depth-first control searches?

Basically are you better off doing a gradient based optimization or attempting many depth first search runs, potentially biasing the runs towards parameters that perform well initially?

Comment: Probably depends, for example gradient based methods can get stuck in local minima.

Comment: hm, a lot of the increased compute power these days goes into neural networks, which are stochastic gradient descent methods; so gradient-based, but stochastic elements. Don't know what kind of answer you're expecting? This looks more like an invitation to talk over a glass of wine than a question that could have a definite answer.

Comment: NN architectures have massive number of parameters, not really the same as real-time systems. I suppose the question is a bit open ended but it amounts to asking if repeated trial runs are better over attempting gradient descent on the control parameter. I haven't seen a lot of work in this area or it being used much in classic control areas, I see it used in CS areas a lot more.